# Background Blur bug on touch devices

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am a UI designer.

I am creating a responsive design where I am using multiple background images. But when I am checking this on touch devices, background image is looking completely blurred and ugly.

Below is my CSS code:

```
.bg-1 {background: url("../images/1.jpg"); background-attachment: fixed; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-size: cover; background-repeat:repeat-y; background-position:100% 0; position:relative; min-height:800px;
```

Comment: You should provide more information, like the html structure, the background image or its dimensions in pixels and the dimensions of the device(s).

Comment: I have solved this problem. Thanks.

Want to ask another question about CSS:
Can anyone tell me why background position fixed does not work on touch devices or is there any alternate for this?

Comment: It might not work because of the different viewports. Try using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` on your document's `<head>` and see if it works. This is a nice article for you to read too: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html (read part 2 too)